# Strange Internal server error on Synapse pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I received the below error on Synapse pipeline. I am running pipeline with more cluster size with memory optimized clusters. I am just processing 7-8 JSON files of around 90MB of size each.

Error

> { "errorCode": "145", "message": "Internal Server Error in Synapse
> batch operation: '[plugins.C4T-PRIV-SAW-CAS.IR-Test.19
> WorkspaceType: CCID:]
> [Monitoring] Livy Endpoint=[
> https://hubservice1.westeurope.azuresynapse.net:8001/api/v1.0/publish/c1e53348-b457-4afd-a61d-76553bdd369c
> ]. Livy Id=[4] Job failed during run time with state=[dead].'.",
> "failureType": "SystemError", "target": "DF_Load_CustomsShipment",
> "details": [] }

Answer (score 0):

The **internal server errors** are mostly noticed when there is an **intermittent/transient** issue with the dependent service.

If the issue is not auto resolved or you still experience the issue consistently, I would recommend raising a support ticket for the support engineer to investigate.